# Can std::scoped_allocator_adaptor force allocator to be default constructible?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's start with standard requirements of an allocator type:

> 17.6.3.5.4-5
>
> An allocator type X shall satisfy the requirements of **CopyConstructible** (17.6.3.1). The X::pointer, X::const_pointer, X::void_pointer, and X::const_void_pointer types shall satisfy the requirements of NullablePointer(17.6.3.3). No constructor, comparison operator, copy operation, move operation, or swap operation on these types shall exit via an exception. X::pointer and X::const_pointer shall also satisfy the requirements for a random access iterator (24.2).

```
template <class Tp>
struct SimpleAllocator {
  typedef Tp value_type;
  SimpleAllocator(ctor args);
  template <class T> SimpleAllocator(const SimpleAllocator<T>& other);

  Tp* allocate(std::size_t n);
  void deallocate(Tp* p, std::size_t n);
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const SimpleAllocator<T>&, const SimpleAllocator<U>&);
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const SimpleAllocator<T>&, const SimpleAllocator<U>&);
```

And what does the standard say about `scoped_allocator_adaptor`:

> 20.13.3.1
>
> scoped_allocator_adaptor();
>
> Effects:
>   value-initializes the OuterAlloc base class and the inner allocator object.

I am using my allocator in trivial way.

```
template<typename T>
using sa_t =
std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<SimpleAllocator<T>> ;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int, sa_t<int>> xxx{ sa_t{ SimpleAllocator{Arg{}} } };
  return 0;
}
```

Question is:

Does this mean that scoped_allocator_adaptor implies that a minimal allocator interface is not enough and empty-state allocator has to be provided?

Am I allowed to create an allocator that can be default constructed, but which can throw on any requests to allocate/deallocate memory? In other words: is the scoped_allocator_adaptor clients (I am looking at you, standard containers) forced to ignore such default constructed adaptor?

Comment: If your allocator is not DefaultConstructible, then you can't use the default constructor of `scoped_allocator_adaptor` or `vector`. You'd have to use the `template <class OuterA2> scoped_allocator_adaptor(OuterA2&& outerAlloc, const InnerAllocs&... innerAllocs) noexcept;` constructor for `scoped_allocator_adaptor` and the vector constructor that takes an allocator argument.

Comment: @T.C. The point is that I know (and accept the fact) that I will be creating vector only when I pass the scoped_allocator object.